# Reloading the $PATH from the GUI terminal

Tags: terminal, path

My machine is running Fedora 16 x86_64

I am trying to figure out why I can not get my GUI terminal window to refresh the path.

I recently added a new location to the path (in `.bash_profile`), after closing the GUI terminal and reopening it, the new location is still not showing. When I go to `tty2` the new path is listed. I closed the GUI terminal and reopened again to find the new path entry still is not in the path being used. I did not reboot but I am trying to:

1. avoid rebooting
2. figure out what I need to do so that I do not run into this problem again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shell profile - for bash, `~/.bash_profile` - is only loaded when you start a *login* shell.  A non-login shell uses `~/.bashrc`.

At a guess your terminal is starting a non-login shell for a new tab or window, which means that your change won't be seen until you log off and back on again.

You might consider setting your path in `.bashrc`, or you might set your terminal program to start login shells instead.  (I generally prefer the later, but YMMV)

Comment: Also, and ad-hoc solution is just `source ~/.bash_profile` to make it happen right now. And I agree with Daniel, the problem is that you have to logout and login in X in order to apply the settings from your profile.